# Writing a dict to txt file and reading it back?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a dictionary to a txt file. Then read the dict values by typing the keys with `raw_input`. I feel like I am just missing one step but I have been looking for a while now.

I get this error

```
File "name.py", line 24, in reading
    print whip[name]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import exit

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.address = ""
        self.phone = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.whip = {}

    def writing(self):
        self.whip[p.name] = p.age, p.address, p.phone
        target = open('deed.txt', 'a')
        target.write(str(self.whip))
        print self.whip

    def reading(self):
        self.whip = open('deed.txt', 'r').read()
        name = raw_input("> ")
        if name in self.whip:
            print self.whip[name]

p = Person()

while True:
    print "Type:\n\t*read to read data base\n\t*write to write to data base\n\t*exit to exit"
    action = raw_input("\n> ")
    if "write" in action:
        p.name = raw_input("Name?\n> ")
        p.phone = raw_input("Phone Number?\n> ")
        p.age = raw_input("Age?\n> ")
        p.address = raw_input("Address?\n>")
        p.writing()
    elif "read" in action:
        p.reading()
    elif "exit" in action:
        exit(0)
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: `name 'p' is not defined`, p should be an instance of Person class

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Your code is *almost right*!  You are right, you are just missing one step.  When you read in the file, you are reading it as a string; but you want to turn the string back into a dictionary.

The error message you saw was because `self.whip` was a string, not a dictionary.  So you need to convert the string to a dictionary.

### Example

Here is the simplest way: feed the string into `eval()`.  Like so:

```
def reading(self):
    s = open('deed.txt', 'r').read()
    self.whip = eval(s)
```

You can do it in one line, but I think it looks messy this way:

```
def reading(self):
    self.whip = eval(open('deed.txt', 'r').read())
```

But `eval()` is sometimes not recommended.  The problem is that `eval()` will evaluate *any* string, and if someone tricked you into running a really tricky string, something bad might happen.  In this case, you are just running `eval()` on your own file, so it should be okay.

But because `eval()` is useful, someone made an alternative to it that is safer.  This is called `literal_eval` and you get it from a Python module called `ast`.

```
import ast

def reading(self):
    s = open('deed.txt', 'r').read()
    self.whip = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

`ast.literal_eval()` will only evaluate strings that turn into the basic Python types, so there is no way that a tricky string can do something bad on your computer.

### EDIT

Actually, best practice in Python is to use a `with` statement to make sure the file gets properly closed.  Rewriting the above to use a `with` statement:

```
import ast

def reading(self):
    with open('deed.txt', 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
        self.whip = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

In the most popular Python, known as "CPython", you usually don't need the `with` statement as the built-in "garbage collection" features will figure out that you are done with the file and will close it for you.  But other Python implementations, like "Jython" (Python for the Java VM) or "PyPy" (a really cool experimental system with just-in-time code optimization) might not figure out to close the file for you.  It's good to get in the habit of using `with`, and I think it makes the code pretty easy to understand.

Comment: `dict()` expects a dictionary or a list of tuples. It won't evaluate a string.

Comment: @Blender Oh, you are right and I'm tired.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Nick: Try running it first ;)

Comment: @Blender, thank you for the heads-up.  And since I am tired I think I will stop posting on StackOverflow for the night! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please give an example of a 'tricky' string on which using eval() is dangerous?

Comment: @arman_aegit I did a quick search and found a StackOverflow answer giving examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082  The examples show how a correctly crafted string can run an arbitrary command (with the privileges of the user).  Also it would be possible for it to overwrite any file that the user can write to, opening all sorts of privilege-escalation attacks.

Answer (score 199):

Have you tried [the json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)? JSON format is very similar to python dictionary. And it's human readable/writable:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {"one":1, "two":2}
>>> json.dump(d, open("text.txt",'w'))
```

This code dumps to a text file

```
$ cat text.txt 
{"two": 2, "one": 1}
```

Also you can load from a JSON file:

```
>>> d2 = json.load(open("text.txt"))
>>> print d2
{u'two': 2, u'one': 1}
```

Comment: should you open the file for reading/writing in a `with` statement to ensure it closes after?

Comment: I experienced problems using this method on some complex dictionaries such has having nested set values (e.g. `d = {"one": {"1" : 1, "a": {"i"}}}`). Therefore, I recommend @blender's pickle method that works in my case.

Comment: Note that python's json translates dict keys to **strings** when doing json.dump, so `json.dump({1: 'one'}, file)` will read back as `{'1': 'one'}` when doing json.load. Better to use pickle if you are not going to read the saved file using other languages than Python.

Comment: Is there a way to using something like json.dumps( dict_x, indent=4) to format the way the dict is written to the file to make it more legible? When I use your code the entire dict is written to one line, no matter how large it is, and it's not easily human readable.

Comment: Nvm! I figured it out. I read the file like so `dict_x = json.loads(database_file.read())` and write to it like so `database_file.write(json.dumps(dict_x, indent = 4))`. It's much more legible now. Perhaps I was using your code incorrectly and yours produced a legible text file from a large dict too but this worked for me for a large dict. `database_file` is a `File` object FYI

Comment: PSA: `json.loads` and `json.load` cannot decode multiple dicts from a file

Answer (score 75):

To store Python objects in files, use the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module:

```
import pickle

a = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
}

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(a, handle)

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as handle:
  b = pickle.loads(handle.read())

print a == b # True
```

Notice that I never set `b = a`, but instead pickled `a` to a file and then unpickled it into `b`.

As for your error:

```
self.whip = open('deed.txt', 'r').read()
```

`self.whip` was a dictionary object. `deed.txt` contains text, so when you load the contents of `deed.txt` into `self.whip`, `self.whip` becomes the *string* representation of itself.

You'd probably want to evaluate the string back into a Python object:

```
self.whip = eval(open('deed.txt', 'r').read())
```

Notice how `eval` sounds like `evil`. That's intentional. Use the `pickle` module instead.

Comment: no it gives me this error  File "name.py", line 24, in reading
    print whip[name]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str             I thought p = Person() defined it

Comment: That text isn't in your code. Before asking a question, explain what's wrong.

Comment: _To store Python objects in files, use the pickle module_ Unless these are config files so you want them to be editable by human - see [Why bother with python and config files?](http://www.robg3d.com/?p=1000)

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I need: to store native python structure state in a file that is not intended to be user editable.

Comment: This method works perfectly for complex dictionaries as I described in my comment for the JSON method suggested by @KFL

Answer (score 12):

Hi there is a way to write and read the dictionary to file you can turn your dictionary to JSON format and read and write quickly just do this :

To **write** your date:

```
 import json

 your_dictionary = {"some_date" : "date"}
 f = open('destFile.txt', 'w+')
 f.write(json.dumps(your_dictionary))
```

and to **read** your data:

```
 import json

 f = open('destFile.txt', 'r')
 your_dictionary = json.loads(f.read())
```

Answer (score 8):

I created my own functions which work really nicely:

```
def writeDict(dict, filename, sep):
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        for i in dict.keys():            
            f.write(i + " " + sep.join([str(x) for x in dict[i]]) + "\n")
```

It will store the keyname first, followed by all values. Note that in this case my dict contains integers so that's why it converts to `int`. This is most likely the part you need to change for your situation.

```
def readDict(filename, sep):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        dict = {}
        for line in f:
            values = line.split(sep)
            dict[values[0]] = {int(x) for x in values[1:len(values)]}
        return(dict)
```

Comment: Great code if your values are not too long.
My dictionary included multiple long strings which just got cut off with '...'

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate through the key-value pair and write it into file

```
pair = {'name': name,'location': location}
with open('F:\\twitter.json', 'a') as f:
     f.writelines('{}:{}'.format(k,v) for k, v in pair.items())
     f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to import json or pickle - I'm not sure why but no above or other answers work for me. I finally wrote this which works.  Seems like saving and opening a dict would be easier than this.

```
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    for i in dic.keys():            
        f.write(i + ":" + str(dic[i])+'\n')

mydict = {}
with open(fname, mode='r') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        s = line.split(':')
        mydict[s[0]] = s[1].split('\n')[0]
print(mydict)
```