# Importing a function from a .txt file

Tags: python

Is there any way to do this?

Basically I have a file that I want a user to be able to edit via a GUI I built(all of which I can do easily). Part of this is a calculation in a function. That or being able to edit a .py file from another file would be fine as well, but it is hard to find anything on that because every search returns details about IDLE and such.

I also have no problem with just having the calculation only in the text file and being able to read that from the text file and then parse it to add the variables in, but not even sure how to do that easily either, with the calculations varying like so:

(abs(x) - abs(y) * dict['t']) * 18

((abs(y) * dict['t']) - abs(x)) * 20

etc for about 10 different variations

Comment: you can evaluate a string with eval()

Comment: Use `eval` if the file is safe/runs on client machine

Comment: dup and answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/11027069/1107807

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python writing dict to txt file and reading dict from txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/python-writing-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-dict-from-txt-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup, its not at all secure, but `eval` is the way to go:

```
In [1]: a= 10
In [2]: b= 20
In [3]: eval('a + 10*b')
Out[3]: 210
```

Comment: [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would add some security.