# Save URL with dictionary text and escape characters to dictionary (ignore/remove escape characters)

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I'm trying to write the contents of a URL (not a text file) to a dictionary. The URL has a dictionary of dictionaries in text like so:

```
{{"id":15160,"icimsId":247092,"shortDescription":"ABC Leadership Development Program - Retail & Consumer\n\n\u00a3 Competitive basic salary + sign on bonuses + benefits\nClosing date: 30th June 2014\n\nWork hard. Have fun. Make history.\n\nABC opened its","url":"\/jobs\/247092\/ABC-mba-leadership-development-program-uk","title":"ABC MBA Leadership Development Program (UK) ","jobCategory":"Buying, Planning, & Instock Management","location":"GB, Slough","teamCategory":"University Recruiting","team":null}}
```

My guess is to save this URL as a TXT file and then use this approach:

[Writing a dict to txt file and reading it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/python-writing-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-dict-from-txt-file)

However, I'm struggling because once I make it into a txt file and try to eval it, the escape characters cause some issues.

Meanwhile this works just fine:

```
dict_string = r"""{{"id":15160,"icimsId":247092,"shortDescription":"ABC Leadership Development Program - Retail & Consumer\n\n\u00a3 Competitive basic salary + sign on bonuses + benefits\nClosing date: 30th June 2014\n\nWork hard. Have fun. Make history.\n\nABC opened its","url":"\/jobs\/247092\/ABC-mba-leadership-development-program-uk","title":"ABC MBA Leadership Development Program (UK) ","jobCategory":"Buying, Planning, & Instock Management","location":"GB, Slough","teamCategory":"University Recruiting","team":null}}"""

dict_string = eval(dict_string)
print dict_string["jobs"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of possible solutions, I propose to use `json` module, to parse this string.

Something like this:

```
import json

with open('file_with_dict.txt', 'r') as f:
    dict_string = json.load(f)

print(dict_string['jobs'])
```

Hope, this help you.

Comment: Thanks drjackild. I just tried that and got an error "TypeError: excpected string or buffer"

Comment: @pugmastaflex Sorry, my bad. I've edit answer. Use json.load() instead of json.loads()