# cannot send pyspark output to a file in the local file system

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a pyspark job on spark (single node, stand-alone) and trying to save the output in a text file in the local file system.

```
input = sc.textFile(inputfilepath)
words = input.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
wordCount = words.countByValue()

wordCount.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/username/output.txt")
```

I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

Basically whatever I add to 'wordCount' object, for example collect() or map() it returns the same error. The code works with no problem when output goes to the terminal (with a for loop) but I can't figure what is missing to send the output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countByValue()` [method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.countByKey) that you're calling is returning a dictionary of word counts. This is just a standard python dictionary, and doesn't have any Spark methods available to it.

You can use [your favorite method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/python-writing-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-dict-from-txt-file) to save the dictionary locally.

Comment: Beat me to it.  @Snoozer is 100% correct.  countByValue doesnt create a new RDD, its a local dictionary.

Comment: Thanks... I changed it to `map(lambda x: (str(x),1)).reduceByKey(add)` with `from operator import add`