# How should I read/write a data structure containing large arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, file-io

I fetch a big array of data from a server. I store it in a combination of a dictionary and multi-dimensional array, and it will be used for a simple plot. It looks like:

```
>> print(data)
{'intensity_b2': [array([  1.46562588e+09,   1.46562588e+09,   1.46562588e+09, ...,
     1.46566369e+09,   1.46566369e+09,   1.46566369e+09]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])]}
>> print(len(data['intensity_b2'][0]))
37071
```

To avoid fetching the data every time I run the script I want to save this data structure to a file. I try to store the data as

```
with open("data.dat", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(data))
```

and read it with

```
with open(data_store, 'r') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/python-writing-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-dict-from-txt-file). However, I get an error

> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x108fce5f8>

which I suspect is due to the fact that the data gets stored with the `...` as was shown in the first printout (i.e. the first `print(data)` above is literally how the data looks in the file). How do I write a dictionary with a big array to a file and read it subsequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickle` to handle serialization properly:

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
{'intensity_b2': [array('f', [1465625856.0, 1465625856.0, 1465625856.0]),
  array('f', [1465663744.0, 1465663744.0, 1465663744.0])]}

In [24]: pickle.dump(a, open('foo.p', 'wb'))

In [25]: aa = pickle.load(open('foo.p', 'rb'))

In [26]: aa
Out[26]: 
{'intensity_b2': [array('f', [1465625856.0, 1465625856.0, 1465625856.0]),
  array('f', [1465663744.0, 1465663744.0, 1465663744.0])]}
```

This does exactly what you want to do: saves your data structure to a file, and then reads it from the file.

However, it looks like you're reinventing the wheel here. You may want to have a look at `numpy` and `pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reinventing the wheel how so? The data will be used purely for plotting.

Comment: Guessing from the detais you've provided, you receive data from a  remote server, then convert it into a dictionary of nested arrays, then save it into a file.
`pandas` and `numpy` provide highly efficient data structures to store large data sets. You don't have to build a dictionary of arrays, you can use `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame`. Both modules have built-in tools to handle serialization and saving to files, and `pandas` (which is a higher level module than `numpy`) can convert data to and from virtually any format (json, csv, ....).

Comment: @pingul it depends on what exactly you do between receiving the data from a server, and saving it into a file (and whether you build plots in python). I'm just saying that if you do some data manipulation, it may happen that `pandas` already has a built-in tool for that.

Comment: I actually call a python API that already provide the information as shown. No modification of significance is made. Your input is however appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `str` is not a suitable way to serialise data. Typically, objects will have a string representation that would let a human understand what they are. For primitive objects, it would be a format that you could even `eval` to get back an equivalent object, but this isn't true generally.

You need to decide how you want to serialise the data. You could use something like [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but then you'd need to figure out how to convert object too/from primitive data types anyway, and I think it's already clear that you're not using just primitive data types.

You probably want to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to create a serialised version of the data which which you will be able to unpickle later and get the same data types back.