# How to check an input for keywords from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, keyword

I am trying to make a programme which diagnoses a computer problem based on user input and checks for keywords. I want the keywords to be in a text file. This is the code I have so far, but it reads the keywords from the variable `d`, not from a text file.

```
d = {'screen': 'Get a new screen', ...}
problem = input('What did you do? ').lower()
for k in d:
    if k in problem:
        print(d[k])
```

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/python-writing-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-dict-from-txt-file

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your text file in JSON format and use python's `json.load(your_file_name)`. An example would be:

```
# text file: diagnostics.json 
import json

problems_db = {} # initialize this global variable with default value
with open('diagnostics.json') as fp:
    db_content = json.load(fp)

problem = input('What did you do? ').lower()
for k in problems_db:
    if k in problem:
        print(d[k])
```

Example:

```
// diagnostics.json
{
  "slow": "restart your computer",
  "stuck": "restart your computer", 
  "not loading": "wait a few seconds, then restart your computer"
}
```

User interaction:

```
"What did you do?" "my computer is really slow"
"restart your computer"
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with a .txt file? my mac's textedit does not save in JSON format

Comment: Of course, you can just use this format but change the extension to .txt

Comment: On a slightly irrelevant note, why not using VS Code or Sublime Text, among all great text editors out there,  as text editor to maintain this file?

Comment: when i change the extensions of diagnostics.json to .txt i get a long error code??? I am a python noob who need guidance

Comment: @mr.python just tested myself and it seems to work. Did it work when extension is `.json`?

Comment: why would i still import json if I'm using a .txt file?

Comment: where it says fp, do i put the name and file extension of my text file? sorry I'm so noob

Comment: @mr.python no worries, using `import json` is because with JSON, you can access your data with key-value pairs very easily; for your second question, fp is just a variable here, just make sure the `fp` in the `with` statement is consistent with the `json.load(fp)` expression.