# Covert string from file into already-made dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What I'm trying to do, is backup a dictionary into a text file. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
with open("dict.txt","r") as dict_file:
    text = dict_file.read()
    my_dict = text
```

Of course, this makes a variable called 'my_dict' but saves what is in the text file as a string.

Inside the text file, I have this:

```
{"test":["test0","test1"],"dict":["dict0","dict1","dict2"]}
```

If you are wondering why I'm doing this, it is for a challenge I am doing with my friends where we have to make a user-database thing with importing and exporting users to a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a dict to txt file and reading it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026959/writing-a-dict-to-txt-file-and-reading-it-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ast module` to convert the sting object to a dictionary.

**Ex**:

```
import ast
d = '{"test":["test0","test1"],"dict":["dict0","dict1","dict2"]}'
print(ast.literal_eval(d))
```

**Output**:

```
{"test":["test0","test1"],"dict":["dict0","dict1","dict2"]}
```

Or you can use the `JSON module`.

**Ex:**

```
import json
with open("dict.txt","r") as dict_file:
    text = json.load(dict_file)
```

Comment: Decoding JSON string using literal_eval is definitely not the preferred way. That's what the json module is for.

Comment: `json.load` is for file. `json.loads` is for string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open("dict.txt", 'r') as dict_file:
    my_dict = json.load(dict_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. It's always good practice to add some additional comments to your answer and why it solves the problem, rather than just posting a code snippet.